# binding to an object returned by a service function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following function in an Angular service:

```
    this.getTasks = function() {
        return $http.post(endpoint, params)
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data);
            return response.data;
        });
    };
```

I then try to bind the return value to a variable in my controller by first executing the service function, and using .then() to assign it to a variable:

```
        vm.getTasks = function() {
            LocationGraphService.getTasks()
            .then(function (response.data) {
                vm.tasks = response.data;
            });
        }
```

This doesn't work. I know the service function works as the console.log shows me the data I'm pulling. I need help with calling the function in the controller and assigning it to a variable. Would $q be appropriate here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your service normalizes response object to be `data` property of the original `response`, you don't need to do it one more time in controller. Correct controller logic would be:

```
vm.getTasks = function() {
    LocationGraphService.getTasks()
    .then(function (data) {
        vm.tasks = data;
    });
};
```